# Python function returns True or 1 as None, while returning False and 0 correctly

Tags: python

I have a program that does a simple palindrome check, by comparing each ends of the string and then doing a substring  of the original string recursively. That is, I compare str[0] to str[-1], do a str[1,-1] and repeat the comparisons. What I did find while stepping through the code is, that when I ask the function check_palin() to return 1, it returns None. I can clearly see it 'execute' the return statement, but it always returns None when I ask it to return 1. However, it returns 0 correctly. The same behavior is observed with returning True/False. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong??

```
def check_palin(s):
    global init
    print("Init is %d" %(init))
    if len(s) <= 1 :
        if not init :
            print("returning 1")
            return True
        else :
            print("Please supply a string of atleast 2 characters! Exiting...\n")
            print("returning 0")
            return False
    else :
        init = 0
        if first_word(s) == last_word(s) :
            check_palin(middle(s))
        else :
            print("returning 0")
            return False


def first_word(s) :
    return s[0]

def last_word(s):
    return s[-1]

def middle(s):
    return s[1:-1]

init  = 1
s = raw_input("Please enter a string")
print(check_palin(s))
if not check_palin(s) :
    print ("String %s IS NOT a palindrome!" %(s))
else :
    print ("String %s IS a palindrome!" %(s))

Output:
Please enter a stringababa
Init is 1
Init is 0
Init is 0
returning 1
None
Init is 0
Init is 0
Init is 0
returning 1
String ababa IS NOT a palindrome!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: in python an easier way to check if the s is palindrome is s == s[::-1] . it reverses the string and compares it with original string. I think it is more 'pythonic'. you don't have to check index by index like many low-level languages.

Comment: I was using this, as more of a way to write recursive functions. . But that's a rather neat trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to return the result of your recursion.

```
    if first_word(s) == last_word(s) :
        return check_palin(middle(s))
```

Comment: This is so common this error should have a name, like the Fundamental Recursion Error.

Comment: "Default User Negated Function Usage Contract Dysfunction Ur-Problem"

Comment: Oh boy! That's a rookie mistake, alright! Thanks a lot! Now let me go and hide myself in shame...